# Rails + Devise and Android: Logging in

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, authentication, rest, devise

I'm stuck at implementing login with Rails + Devise using an Android App.

What I want to accomplish is whenever the user logs in; the server responds with his/her credentials (email and user id) so he/she can post comments using the Android app.

**What's the best way to do this?**

This is what I've got so far:

**MobileController (Rails)**

```
def login
  @user = User.where(:email => params[:email])

  respond_to do |format|
    format_json { render :json => @user.to_json }
  end
end
```

And the Android app simply uses HttpClient to make a POST request to http://localhost/mobile/login

Comment: That isn't secure. You can't login by saying "hey i am foo@bar.com", because anyone can say that.

Comment: yeah, as long as he has an account. just did something so i can retrieve the user id.

Answer (score 2):

Devise has the token authentication. I think it better for such user authentication like you do.
The example is here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example

Comment: ah yes, so whenever the user logs in, he/she can just provide the token? in my mobilecontroller, i can just do @user = User.where(:auth_token => params[:auth_token]) and then render it in json?

Comment: You should generate the token and then you can access the application by sending this token. And how the client will get the token it's depends only on your code realization. Maybe it's will be necessary to generate in only once, or each time when user logging in.

Comment: creating the token during registration sounds logical. thanks for this answer. though i would prefer if authentication is done using email and pass.